# VueJs Router links not working on live server

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have created a vuejs project using router links components. Everything works on localhost but fails when deploying the project to a live server, The subdomain path and router links fail on the live server.

The correct path would be `example.com/project_name/public/client` but it is being replaced by `example.com/client`.

> App.js

```
let routes = [
    {path: '/dashboard', component: require('./components/dashboard.vue').default},
    {path: '/client', component: require('./components/client.vue').default},

]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

> Master Blade

```
<div class="page-wrapper" id="app">

  <li>
     <router-link to="/dashboard" title="Dashboard">
     <span class="nav-link-text"><i style="color:white"
       class="fal fa-tachometer-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Dashboard</span>
     </router-link>
  </li>

  <li>
      <router-link to="/client" title="Client">
        <span class="nav-link-text"><i style="color:white" class="fal fa-users"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Client</span>
      </router-link>
  </li>

</div>
```

> web.php

```
Route::prefix('api')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {

    Route::apiResource('clients', 'API\ClientController');

});
```

Methods:

```
methods: {

    getClients() {
                axios.get('api/clients').then(({data}) => (this.clients = data.data));
            },
}
```

Comment: is it working on local server

Comment: Yes everything working fine on local server @sidheart

Comment: code seems look fine try to change this `axios.get('api/clients').then(({data}) => (this.clients = data.data));` to `axios.get('/api/clients').then(({data}) => (this.clients = data.data));`

Comment: already tried this one.. still not working

Comment: Try to set base url `<base href="http://example.com/project_name/public/client/">`

Comment: You can get it by `URL::to('/')` in laravel

Comment: URL::to('/client') is not acceptable. Its showing error

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. You have absolute paths in your router-links which link correctly to the corresponding path: `/client` to `<host>/client`. Are your router links working? And how is related to your getClients() method? ..Here you use relative paths, which will append to your current path.

Comment: @MarcRo Yes router links working on local server and live server but methods are not working.. Methods need full base url to works... not working with example.com/api/clients...

Comment: @DaniyalMughees At which route is your api located? -> try to access this route when you type it in the browser. Is it working?

Comment: the thing is when we deploy project on the domain subdirectory we got a base url with subdirectory .. In my case i am not getting subdirectory url, just getting url like example.com/client which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

creat a .htaccess file and paste it on root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: I put .htaccess file in public_html directory and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

// I have got a solution by changing webpack.mix.js. follow my instruction and try it for yourself.
//First Step: Modify your webpack.mix.js exactly like this

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.config.webpackConfig.output = {
    chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
};
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

// second step: run npm run watch
//third step: copy the chunk folder which is located on public/js/chunk
/ fourth step: now upload this chunk folder on the live server  and move this folder to your project root directory